# Bold some words in a string and remove some unbold words

Tags: php, regex, string

I am creating a search engine. Currently, my script bolds the matching words from the keyword. But some keywords are too long, like the results for **shah rukh khan**:

> 25216d1235653089 **shahrukh khan** s
>   wallpaper **shah rukh** actor

As you see, the above keyword is too long. So, I need it to be like:

> **shahrukh khan** s wallpaper

or

> **shah rukh** actor

---

Currently, I am using the following code, but it requires a space before and after the bold tags. So, if the 1st word is bold, it displays the whole keyword.

```
if(strlen($img_keyword)>30){
    $img_keyword = preg_replace('/(.*?) <b>(.*?)<\/b> (.*?)/us',
      " <b>$2</b> ",
      $img_keyword);
}
```

Is there a way to do/fix this?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Can you state it again?

Comment: I just need to remove un-bold words from a string. This string> "this <b>is the keyword</b> one" to this> "<b>is the keyword</b>"

Comment: That's the wrong way to search. What if someone looks for **rukh shah**?

Comment: And what's wrong with the way you do it right now? It seems to be a regular expression grabbing bold content, what's wrong with that?

Comment: @SanHolo: If someone search for **rukh shah**, it displays **shah rukh** as I am using MySQL Full-Text Search.

Comment: @Pekka Gaiser: The way I use need a space before and after the bold tag. So, if the 1st word is bold, it displays the whole keyword. Ex: "**khan**%2Cposttag **khan** died on 27 april%2Cposttag is no more%2Cposttag the style icon of bollywood"

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I can see, you don't need the spaces in front and after the bold text, so why don't you just remove the space, add a start anchor at the beginning and an end anchor at the end of the pattern? Like this:

```
$img_keyword = preg_replace('/^(.*?)<b>(.*?)<\/b>(.*?)$/us'," <b>$2</b> ",$img_keyword);
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer. Now, when I search, it only displays the first mathcing word as the keyword. Ex: When I search for 'Shah Rukh Khan', keyword of the image is **shah**

Comment: I also tried this **'/^(.*?)<b>(.*?)<\/b>(.*?)/us'** and some image keywords are ok. But, some very long keywords like this **khan %2Cposttag khan died on 27 april%2Cposttag is no more%2Cposttag the style icon of bollywood** are same...

Comment: Sorry. Remove the u modifier. Like this:

    $img_keyword = preg_replace('/^(.*?)<b>(.*?)<\/b>(.*?)$/s'," <b>$2</b> ",$img_keyword);

Answer (score 0):

After **Franz**'s help, I edited my code as I mentioned below.

```
 $img_keyword = boldText($query, $img_keyword);
 if(strlen($img_keyword)>30){
 $img_keyword = preg_replace('/^(.*?)<b>(.*?)<\/b>(.*?)/u',"<b> $2 </b>",$img_keyword);
     }
if(strlen($img_keyword)>30){
$img_keyword = preg_replace('/<\/b>(.*?)<b>/x'," ",$img_keyword);
   }
if(strlen($img_keyword)>30){
$img_keyword = preg_replace('/<\/b>(.*?)$|(.*?)<b>$/x',"</b> ",$img_keyword);
 }
```

---

If the keywords is

> kajol shah rukh vogue india blumarine

the result is

> shah rukh
>
> ---

If the keyword is

> p 18 mFEk4J448M labelsadt 0%2Clanguage en%2Cposttag feroz khan%2Cposttag khan died on 27 april%2Cposttag is no more%2Cposttag the style icon of bollywood

the result is

> khan khan
>
> ---

Is there a way to keep one or two unbold words and remove others?